# Why are my French Cobra bean flowers not being pollinated?

Tags: beans, pollination, green-beans

I have French Cobra bean which I heard is supposed to self pollinate. In the mean time all the flowers just dry out and fall off leaving a small stem behind. It's the first time I grow beans and I would expect that once the flower falls off it would leave fruit behind as with tomatoes.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking why pollination did not occur? Or are you asking whether or not French beans self pollinate? (I'm 99% sure they are capable of doing so).

Comment: Flowers just dry out and fall off instead of pollinate and give fruit, anyone had such problem ?

Comment: As most (probably all?) beans are self pollinating the problem is not the lack of bees or insects, but may be heat stress or lack of water which could cause the flowers to drop (regardless of the presence of pollen). Do you have more info on the growing conditions?

Comment: Looks like it might be water as when I keep compost between being wet and heavy moist I finally got the first small beans there. Thanks a lot for help !

Answer (score 2):

As Lisa pointed out, the cause of beans failing to pollinate is often caused by a lack of water. The plant cannot support a growing fruit with that low of a water level, and aborts the crop. Sweet corn will do the same thing.